# Make String as primary key in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to make `location` (a String) as my primary key for my Spring Boot project.

As a beginner in Spring boot I wonder what will be the best practice here. I want to know the annotations I should use in entities package to make it work without errors.
The table is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE USER 
(
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
EMAIL VARCHAR(20),
PASSWORD VARCHAR(25), 
LOCATION VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (LOCATION),
UNIQUE KEY (EMAIL)
);



CREATE TABLE WANDER
(
  LOCATION VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL, 
  PLACES_TO_EAT VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  VISIT VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  METRO VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (LOCATION)
);
```

My Entity package looks like this:

User.java:

```
package com.hashir.smartcity.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;


@Entity
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String location;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Wander.java

```
package com.hashir.smartcity.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Wander{

    private String location;
    private String placesToEat;
    private String visit;
    private String metro;

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getPlacesToEat() {
        return placesToEat;
    }

    public void setPlacesToEat(String placesToEat) {
        this.placesToEat = placesToEat;
    }

    public String getVisit() {
        return visit;
    }

    public void setVisit(String visit) {
        this.visit = visit;
    }

    public String getMetro() {
        return metro;
    }

    public void setMetro(String metro) {
        this.metro = metro;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, but you don't have to do anything special to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `@Id` annotation.
It is not different when using `@Id` in non-string fields. However, it is a bad practice if you use the **location** field as your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this doc  `@Id String location;`
[Link](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id)